# Difference between --others and --other in git-ls-files

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I want to understand the difference between --others and --other in git-ls-files .
I got same result when i use 'git-ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard' and 'git-ls-files --other -ignored --exclude-standard'.

Comment: Note that writing `git something` as `git-something` is the old (2005) way of invoking the command, and has been deprecated for many years. It will probably stop working in a few more years. Use `git ls-files` rather than `git-ls-files` to avoid having your software break then.

Answer (score 1):

`--other` and `--others` have the same meaning even though `--other`
is not specified in `man git-ls-files`. This is how Git parses options
[as explained](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/api-parse-options);

> Long options may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous.

Comment: Between 'git-ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard' and 'git-ls-files --other -ignored --exclude-standard', which one is correct?

Comment: Neither - it should be `git ls-files`. And you probably mean
`--ignored` because a single minus means multiple short options.